# Sankey Diagram labels in R

Tags: r, dplyr, label, sankey-diagram

**Background**

I am creating a Sankey Diagram in R and I am struggling with labeling the nodes.

As example, I will [reuse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67113888/alluvial-plot-in-r-how-to-space-the-strata) a dataset with 10 imaginary patients that are screened for COVID-19. At baseline, all patients are negative for COVID-19. After let’s say 1 week, all patients are tested again: now, 3 patients are positive, 6 are negative and 1 has an inconclusive result. Yet another week later, the 3 positive patients remain positive, 1 patient goes from negative to positive, and the others are negative.

```
data <- data.frame(patient = 1:10, 
                   baseline = rep("neg", 10), 
                   test1 = c(rep("pos",3), rep("neg", 6), "inconcl"), 
                   test2 = c( rep(NA, 3), "pos", rep("neg", 6) ))
```

**Attempt**

To create the Sankey diagram, I am using the `ggsankey` [package](https://github.com/davidsjoberg/ggsankey):

```
library(tidyverse)
#devtools::install_github("davidsjoberg/ggsankey")
df <- data %>%
  make_long(baseline, test1, test2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node,
               fill = factor(node), label = node)) +
  geom_sankey() +
  geom_sankey_label(aes(fill = factor(node)), size = 3, color = "white") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "green", "red")) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", legend.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

**Question**

I would like to label the `nodes` with the number of patients that are present in each node  (e.g., the first node would be labeled as `10`, and the `inconclusive` node would be labeled as `1`, and so on...).

How do you do this in R without hardcoding the values?

**Parts of solution**

To extract the numbers from the data, I thought the initial step should be something like:

```
data %>% count(baseline, test1, test2)
#  baseline   test1 test2 n
#1      neg inconcl   neg 1
#2      neg     neg   neg 5
#3      neg     neg   pos 1
#4      neg     pos  <NA> 3
```

I think that if I am able to include the proper values in an extra column of the long data `df`, I should be able to call `label=variable_name` from the aesthetics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggsankey)
library(dplyr)


# create a count data frame for each node

df_nr <- 
  df %>% 
  filter(!is.na(node)) %>% 
  group_by(x, node)%>% 
  summarise(count = n())
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'x'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

# join to sankey dataframe

df <- 
  df %>% 
  left_join(df_nr)




ggplot(df, aes(x = x, next_x = next_x, node = node, next_node = next_node,
               fill = factor(node))) +
  geom_sankey() +
  geom_sankey_label(aes(label = node), size = 3, color = "white") +
  geom_sankey_text(aes(label = count), size = 3.5, vjust = -1.5, check_overlap = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("grey", "green", "red")) +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_blank())
```

**data**

```
data <- data.frame(patient = 1:10, 
                   baseline = rep("neg", 10), 
                   test1 = c(rep("pos",3), rep("neg", 6), "inconcl"), 
                   test2 = c( rep(NA, 3), "pos", rep("neg", 6) ))
df <- data %>%
  make_long(baseline, test1, test2)
```

You can adjust the placement of the count label or change it to label if you want a bounding box (not so sure this works so well). Not sure if `geom_sankey_label` recognises `check_overlap` to avoid multiple overlaps of the count text.

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Hi Peter, can you please answer my question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68266728/in-r-how-to-display-value-on-the-links-paths-of-sankey-graph) which is also regarding sankey diagram? I tried a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the response. It's because the version of R have changed. It's ok with R-3.6.1 but not with R-4.3.1